# dispatch mouse event with ctrlKey = true isn't work in IE11 and FireFox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, mouseevent, dispatch

I'm trying to simulate a mouse click event in IE/FireFox browsers when **ctrlKey tag is true**.
I've googled it a lot, but I cannot find why my code isn't working.
What supposed to happen: 
- triggerClick should click the link (that is fine in both IE & FF)
- triggerClickCtrl should open the link in a new tab (in IE - it does the same as the buttom triggerClick, and in FF it does nothing).
- triggerClickShift should open the link in a new window (in IE - it does the same as the buttom triggerClick, and in FF it does nothing).
Note: this code works in chrome, but it doesn't work in IE11 and FireFox.

any suggestions?
Thanks.

```js
function triggerClick()
    {
        simulateClick(false, false, false);
    }


    function triggerClickCtrl()
    {
        simulateClick(true, false, false);
    }

    function triggerClickShift()
    {
        simulateClick(false, true, false);
    }

    var simulateClick = function (ctrl, shift, isMiddle) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, ctrl, false, shift, false, isMiddle ? 1 : 0, null );
        document.getElementById('bingLink').dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p>


<p><a id = 'bingLink' href = "http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></p>


<button onclick=triggerClick()>triggerClick</button>
<button onclick=triggerClickCtrl()>triggerClickCtrl</button>
<button onclick=triggerClickShift()>triggerClickShift</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've also tried to use: new MouseEvent("click", {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            clientX: 10,
            clientY: 10,
            ctrlKey: true
        });
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
} But it gave me the same result.

Comment: same issue here. Did you resolve it now?